# Need suggestion regarding URL structure change for SEO

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t

In our project we are using 3 level deep folder structure to manage our FAQ pages. Those sub directories are defined on the basis of Category, defined by client. Also these structure helps editors to manage their pages(more than 700 pages) .

So the url of the pages are like –

> www.example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/question.html

Now client wants to remove 2 sub directories from the url. As a justification they told that less directory will help to increase the rank of pages in Google search.

I have checked from the different sources and found that the page ranking in Google search does not have any dependency on the url structure level though I want to take the suggestion from you guys.

If this is the case, then one possible way to achieve this requirement is to move all the pages to the parent directory, but in that scenario it will be difficult for the content editors to manage their pages in future.

Therefore I need suggestion from your end –

1. Is there any other way from Tridion side to handle this
   situation?
2. What are the best practices I should follow to achieve this
   situation for any Tridion driven web site.

For Information we are using

> Tridion 2013 SP1 & DD4T 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen a few different implementations for this, I'll list it below - but for now I really need to confirm what you say: URL "depth" does not influence google search results anymore. This was the case 10 years ago, maybe 6-7 years ago still, but not in a long time. Actually, if the URL structure helps describe the content it may even *help* your SEO ranking.

So my recommendation would be "don't do it".

From a technical point of view, I've seen solutions that use deployer extensions or publishing hacks to rename the URL from /something/blah/blah to /something-blah-blah. This seems to be what is still used [here](http://www.aig.com/mortgage-insurance_3171_442090.html) (yes, that's an implementation from 2007, when "short URLs" was an SEO guideline).

Also simple redirects or "[Canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)" can be used to "fix" the google ranking.

But as I said first, I would really question your requirement and ask for the proof/ROI of this change. If it adds to your cost of producing the content, and doesn't add to the ranking, then you're much better off not doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nuno. Yes! I have also asked them to provide the proper clarification for that change. I think I will go for the simple redirect or deployer extension, if they really wants to change. Do you think redirecting url may impact the site performance ?